# Assigning Linux file permissions to multiple users

Tags: linux, file, file-permissions, chmod

For directory `/var/www/` and its subdirectories, I wish users apache, phped, and Michael each to have r/w/x privileges on all existing files as well as future files created by each of these users. How should I do this?

Comment: Uhh, how about a `group`?

Comment: @Two-BitAlchemist.  What I am currently doing is adding apache to phped and Michael group, phped to apache and Michael group, and Michael to phped and apache group.  Wile it works, it gets hard to maintain.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You either want to put all those users in a group and set the group ownership of /var/www to that group. Then you'd want to set the group suid bit with something like `chmod g+rwxs dirname` to make all new files belong to the group.

Or you could use ACLs (Access Control Lists) see for example http://users.suse.com/~agruen/acl/linux-acls/online/
To make all new files belong to some certain group you can set the default ACL for the folder and all new files

[edit]
You create a new group `groupadd mynewgroup` and then `useradd -G mynewgroup Michael` and so on for all the users that should be in that group. Then you'll need to `chgrp -R mynewgroup /var/www/` to set the group ownership of the directory.

Comment: Don't know about ACL, but I will read up on it.  How would you recommend implementing a group?  Please see my comment to Two-BitAlchemist under my original post.

Comment: `chmod g+rwxs`.  Change file mode.  g is for group?  +rwx is obvious, but what about the s?  The Man states `set user or group ID on execution (s)`.  What is this doing?

Comment: You're setting the setgid flag on the directory so that new files inherit the group ownership.

Comment: Ah, that was what I was missing!  Perfectly fine to not create a new group, but just use the group of one of the three users, right?  I would probably pick apache as the group.

Comment: Thats not necessarily a good idea. Then that user will be able to mess with all apache group owned files. Better to have a new group.

Comment: Ended up making recursive `chmod -R g+rwxs /var/www/`

Answer (score 1):

create a group containing these users and assign group level permissions as per your desire.